# Phonegap geolocation.watchPosition not updating location on iPhone

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, gps

I am developing a phonegap application that sends the current GPS location to a server. In order to do so, we have the following code fragment:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(gpsTracker.onNewCoordinates, gpsTracker.onError, {
    enableHighAccuracy : true,
    maximumAge: 4000, //should be default, just in case
    timeout: 5000
});
```

The callback functions take care of submitting the results. On our Android test-device this functionality is working just nicely. However when we run the same code on an iOS device it usually does nothing, except when the GPS reception is fine it will send two coordinates and then it stops.

It looks like iOS only obtains some information once, and never triggers the callback functions when there are new coordinates available.

Anyone with similar experience / solution to this problem?

Comment: As of PhoneGap 1.8.1, this seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my issue as follows. It turns out that `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` does not seem to work well on iOS. I rewrote the code using a javascript `setInterval` which invokes `getCurrentPosition` every 5 seconds instead:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( gpsTracker.onNewCoordinates, gpsTracker.onError, {
    enableHighAccuracy : true,
    maximumAge: 4000, // should be default, just in case
    timeout: 5000
});
```

Now the GPS position is correctly returned every 5 seconds.

Comment: Out of interest have you found a way of running this while the app is minimized/in-the-background?

Comment: In my application we require the app to remain on. On some android devices the logging continues if the screen locks down. On iOS it is possible. Matt Raible created a nice application (http://www.play-more.com) and wrote a very interesting blog about exactly this: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/my_html5_with_play_scala

Comment: I'll save your time. If you need background services like geolocation
or audio, native is necessary. You are forced to use PhoneGap or similar. They add 300 ms delay for touch and won't support background tasks for web applications. This is intended. They want us to create native apps for their stores.

Comment: Could you please post the full code including the setInterval? I am facing the same issue but cant find a way how to implement the setInterval function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/58f7ff98170b16c4 
There is something written about geolocator.start() and stop(), preserved for iOS. Maybe this helps?

According to my experience, the GPS must be "hot" in order to deliver valid positions, i.e. it must be given enough time to connect to satellites etc. Usually, you have it "hot" only if you start watching, not if you just pick single positions. On my HTC, values gained by getCurrentPositions() have therefore turned out too unprecise (related to a near scope, e.g. within 50m). So it might be the right way to try once more to find a solution with startWatching().